# Using ADB, what command can I use to break/permanently destroy a Galaxy S5?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, adb, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I really need to know how to completely fry an S5 (don't ask why) using ADB while attached to a USB to my computer. Someone had posted the instructions for an S4 but the command only turned it off and on again when I used it. If there is any other method I can use to do this (break it I mean, but not physically), let me know.

Comment: Dumb question... Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Requires root access

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0
```

It won't complete through the whole disk, but will proceed to a point where the device flashes black and falls irresponsive. All data are not erased, but the system is gone and it's very hard to recover.

For the same effect:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/mmcblk0 bs=4096 count=256
# Only erases the first 1MB, where the GPT table lies
```

Alternatively (for Galaxy S5 and other "modern" phones):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/by-name/aboot
```

An aftersale service can recover the device without breaking it open, which is what you wanted. I'm not going to post any details about recovery, only the fact that it **can** be recovered.

Comment: do you know a command that doesn't require root access?

Comment: @Jay AFAIK there doesn't exist one.

Answer (score -1):

If you have root right then its very simple. with adb command

```
$ adb shell rm /system/bin/linker
```

you can also try this with terminal emulater with root permission

this will remove executable linker which is very important for .so library in system or in apps.
after reboot i'm sure you can't access your device.
but if you want it back you can use flash tool to flash stock ram and get running it back.
you can also try to remove some other binary in system part.